# How to fix “Object of class WP_Term could not be converted to string”?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to loop through each post I have and get the taxonomy/category id. After that I want to output those ids into a single string (not as a numeric value), separated by a space.

I get this error when I try to echo the string: "Object of class WP_Term could not be converted to string"

Here is what i have so far:

```
<?php
          $taxonomy = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'categories');
          $ids = "";
           
          foreach ($taxonomy as $cat) {
              $ids .= $cat;
          }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message suggests, `wp_get_object_terms` returns an array of `WP_Term` objects. If you want to get the id from the term object, you can use `$term_object->term_id`.

In your code, you should be using `$cat->term_id` (and you are also adding them all to the string without any spaces so I've added a space in too):

```
$taxonomy = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'categories');
$ids = "";
       
foreach ($taxonomy as $cat) {
    $ids .= " ".$cat->term_id;  // het the id from the term object
}
```

**Reference:**

- [WP Code Reference for `WP_Term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/)
- [WP Code Reference for `wp_get_object_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_object_terms/)